# Store last variable in a for loop equation into an array

Tags: r, algorithm

I'm trying to calculate the probability of extinction of a fictional lizard population size. To do this, I am running a for loop for 100 simulations over a period of 30 years, and seeing the probability of each simulation from going extinct. At the end of my 100 simulations, I need to plot a histogram depicting the final population size at the end of the 30 year interval. I figured that the easiest way to plot the histogram would be to create a different vector, and store the final population size of each simulation into this vector (`pop`). However, I have no idea how to code for this and have not found an answer online for my predicament.

I am using the following code:

```
tmax <- 31
runmax <- 100
Year <- 0:(tmax-1)
N <- numeric(tmax) %vector for the population size
N <- N + 1
epsilon <- numeric(tmax) 
rmax <- 0.87992 %maximum growth rate (a value previously calculated)
K <- 34.64252 %carrying capacity (a value previously calculated)
N[1] <- K
extinct <- 0

for(t in 2:tmax){
    sdr <- 0.9469428
    epsilon[t-1] <- rnorm(1,0,sdr) %this takes into account the random population stochasticity (random chance a population will go extinct)
    N[t] <- exp(rmax*(1-(N[t-1]/K))+epsilon[t-1])*N[t-1]
    if(N[t] < 1.0) {
        N[t] <- 0.0;break
    }
    pop=numeric(runmax)
    pop[1]=N[30]
}

extinct <- extinct + ifelse(N[tmax]<=1,1,0)

plot(Year,N,type='l',ylim=c(0,200))

for(i in 1:runmax){
    N <- numeric(tmax)
    N <- N+1
    N[1] <- K
    for(t in 2:tmax){
        sdr <- 0.9469428
        epsilon[t-1] <- rnorm(1,0,sdr) 
        N[t] <- exp(rmax*(1-(N[t-1]/K))+epsilon[t-1])*N[t-1]
        if(N[t] < 1.0) {
            N[t] <- 0.0
            break
        }
    for(w in 2:runmax){
        pop[w]<- N[30]
    }
}

extinct <- extinct + ifelse(N[tmax]<=1,1,0)
lines(Year,N,col=i)
}
```

So in the above code, `pop` is the vector where I'm storing the population at `N[30]`. The idea is then to use `hist(pop)` to plot the histogram.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably add some context. Right now I see many variables and I think some probability density with `rmax` and `K` and `N` and `epsilon`

Comment: Its worth noting that `hist(pop)` is the noise the lizard makes when it goes extinct.

Comment: In the first loop, you are writing over `pop` on each time through the loop -- why? In the second, it is unclear what you are actually saving in the `pop` variable, but it appears to be writing over the results each time again (here, setting all the values of `pop` to `N[30]` for the most recent time through the loop on `i`. Why not set `pop[i] <- N[30]` instead (without the loop on `w`)?

Comment: @KenS. I went back and added some edits. Is that enough context, or what else do you need?

Comment: @MarkPeterson I am not 100% sure what I was doing - I realized I was writing over the results each time the loop went through, but I had no idea how to not do that. Your suggestion of using pop[i]<-N[30] instead of using the loop with the w was a very good one, and it did help a lot. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the results in a matrix like this:

```
pop=matrix(rep(0,runmax*tmax),ncol=tmax)
for(i in 1:runmax){
  N <- numeric(tmax)
  N <- N+1 # this can be removed
  N[1] <- K
  for(t in 2:tmax){
    sdr <- 0.9469428 # this could be placed outside the loops
    epsilon[t-1] <- rnorm(1,0,sdr)
    N[t] <- exp(rmax*(1-(N[t-1]/K))+epsilon[t-1])*N[t-1]
    if(N[t] < 1.0) {N[t] <- 0.0}
    pop[i,t]=N[t]
    if(N[t] ==0) {break}
  }

  extinct <- extinct + ifelse(N[tmax]<=1,1,0)
  lines(Year,N,col=i)
}
hist(pop[,tmax])  #simulation results for tmax
```